# Finding the number of possible arithmetic series of 3 among a given set of numbers

Tags: algorithm

Given a set integers, the problem consists of finding the number of possible arithmetic series of length 3. The set of integers may or may not be sorted.

I could implement a simple bruteforce algorithm taking time O(n^3) but time efficiency is important and the set of integers can be as large as 10^5. This means bruteforce obviously won't work. Can anyone suggest some algorithm/pseudocode/code in c++?

An example: there are 4 numbers 5,2,7,8 . Clearly there is only one such possibility - (2,5,8) in which the common difference is 3, so our answer is 1.

**EDIT**:I forgot to mention one important property - each number of set given is between 1 to 30000 (inclusive).

Comment: guess is that we sort numbers in O(n log n) and remove duplicacy , but removing duplicacy can be used just as optimization , not as actual algorithm . But i think solution revolves somewhere around here , the problem becomes interesting due to its constraints .

Comment: Sounds familiar : http://www.codechef.com/NOV12/problems/COUNTARI

Comment: Problem is *almost* same because *that is* the problem ;)

Comment: @user1795954 if you are also Maggi Iggam please ask a moderator to reconnect your accounts (you can flag this question to do so.) Otherwise editing the question to add more information will continue to be rejected.

Comment: @KateGregory : gud observation , but it is not so - i knew the question source was from codechef so i private messaged Maggi Iggam (he is in my contacts) to add that important propert :)

Comment: @amanmadaan : Well you are absolutly correct ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in O(N^2) as follows: create a hash set of your integers so that you could check a presence or absence of an element in `O(1)`. After that, make two nested loops over all pairs of set elements `{X, Y}`. This is done in `O(N^2)`.

For each pair `{X, Y}`, assume that `X < Y`, and calculate two numbers:

```
Z1 = X - (Y-X)
Z2 = Y + (Y-X)
```

A triple `{X, Y, Zi}` form an arithmetic sequence if `Zi != X && Zi != Y && set.contains(Zi)`

Check both triples `{X, Y, Z1}` and `{X, Y, Z2}`. You can do it in `O(1)` using a hash set, for a total running time of the algorithm of `O(N^2)`.

Comment: thanks very much , but i think O(n) solution also exist , can you please use property i have just added now ? Maybe that can lead your superb brain to O(n) :)

Comment: @user1795954 I don't think you can do it in `O(N)`, but with the limits of 30K you can use an array of booleans (counters if your set is really a bag that allows duplicates) instead of a hash set to perform your checks much faster.

Comment: Yepp i agree with you @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , what do you think now after reading answer below :P

Comment: @MaggiIggam It may be workable, but it's almost certainly an overkill for a codechef-level problem.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution that is O(N+BlogB) (where B is the maximum size of the integers - in your case 30,000) is to consider the histogram H, where H[x] is the number of times x is present in the sequence.

This histogram can be computed in time N.

You are seeking elements a,b,c such that b-a=c-b.  This is equivalent to 2b=a+c.

So the idea is to compute a second histogram G[x] for a+c and then loop through all elements b and add H[b]*G[2b] to the total.  This takes time O(B).

(G[x] is the number of times in the sequence there are a pair of values a,b such that x=a+b.)

The only difficulty is computing G[x], but this can be done using the Fast Fourier Transform to convolve H[x] with itself in time O(BlogB).

Comment: It appears to be a very potential solution (vote up) , but i really cudnt understand completly , so can you supply code snippet ?

Comment: There is a detailed explanation (including code samples) of how to do the convolution at hebb.mit.edu/courses/9.29/2002/readings/c13-1.pdf

Comment: Hey , man that was excellent , bit it went much off my head :D