# Identifying Arithmetic progressions in a list of numbers

Tags: python, math

M arithmetic progressions each having N terms (with the terms differing by d1,d2,...dm) are passed as input with the terms shuffled. The program must print the terms in M arithmetic progressions in sequential order with the smallest starting term first.

Example Input/Output 1:

```
Input: 2
       1 4 8 12 7 16 
Output: 1 4 7 8 12 16
Explanation: There are two progressions. Hence 6/2 = 3 terms in each progression. So the first A.M has 1 4 7 and the second has 8 12 16 As 1 < 8, 1 4 7 is printed followed by 8 12 16
```

Example Input/Output 2:

```
Input: 3
       2 6 8 10 15 22 12 11 4
Output: 2 4 6 8 15 22 10 11 12
```

Explanation: There are three progressions. Hence 9/3 = 3 terms in each progression. So the first A.M has 2 4 6 and the second has 8 15 22. The third has 10 11 12. Note: We cannot have 8 10 12 as the second progression as the remaining numbers 11 15 22 do not for an arithmetic progression.`

I thought of an approach to initially sort the numbers and then generate a list of lists containing the difference of each number with every other number.

```
inp=raw_input()
inputList=[int(c) for c in inp]
inputList.sort()
for i in range(0,len(inputList)):
   for j in range(0,len(inputList)):
      if(i!=j): #To avoid zeros
         newlist.append(abs(inputList[j]-inputList[i]))
```

Then, map each of the numbers in the same place with that in the other list. Thus, a sequence can be identified. But it didn't work out. Is there a better way to solve this problem (preferably in Python)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the number of possible arithmetic series of 3 among a given set of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324832/finding-the-number-of-possible-arithmetic-series-of-3-among-a-given-set-of-numbe)

Comment: @freakish No. That question has a fixed limit of only 3 numbers per progression. Here, the can be greater than or equal to 3 numbers in each progression and a maximum of 5 progressions in the input.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this problem has a well-defined output. For example, an input of `[1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23]` can be interpreted as `[[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23]]` or as `[[1, 11, 21], [2, 12, 22], [3, 13, 23]]`, and there isn't a clear reason to prefer one or the other.

Comment: @user2357112 Since the second AP [2,12,22] has a smaller first term compared to the first's [11,121,13], the second will be given priority!

Comment: vote to close; this question belongs on Programmers SE because it is an algorithms question and due to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-programmers-se. This is not a "details of programming" question (SO).

Comment: @Tommy Algorithms questions are explicitly on topic per [help/on-topic]. Additionally, given that the asker is looking for a Python implementation of this algorithm, I would say that it is off-topic on Programmers, but on topic here.

Comment: @durron597 then this is a problem in the help center(s) because that Meta and Programmers SE explicitly states "algorithms and data structures" are for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Tommy There is some overlap in scope. In such cases, you do not migrate.

Comment: If the author had posted the algorithm to use and had questions about how this would best be done in Python, I would agree with you RE the python bit. Questions of the form "how do I solve this and then how do I do it in language X" are not great questions for SO from reading Meta. Also, if variables were given to represent the numbers in the lists, this could possibly be even re-worded for mathexchange or maybe even computer science. I gather this from reading this very detailed meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in

Comment: @Tommy `icanhazcodez` questions are marginal on both sites.  They're probably a better fit here.

Comment: @Tommy I have given my part of the code in the question. Since it does not work, I seek a better approach. That can very well be asked in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the combinations of the list after sorting in descending order filtering by checking if the elements are  arithmetic progressions then use a Counter dict to keep track of what elements have been used to handle what should be added:

```
def arith_seq(l, m):
    l.sort(reverse=True)
    terms = len(l) // m
    combs = filter(lambda x: all((x[i + 1] - x[i] == x[1] - x[0]
                                       for i in range(len(x) - 1))), combinations(l, terms))
    out = []
    from collections import Counter
    cn = Counter(l)
    for ele in combs:
        if all(cn[c] > 0 for c in ele):
            out.append(ele[::-1])
            for c in ele:
                cn[c] -= 1
    out.sort()
    return out
```

Using your input:

```
In [6]: inp = 3

In [7]: l = map(int,"2 6 8 10 15 22 12 11 4".split())

In [8]: arith_seq(l,inp)
Out[8]: [(2, 4, 6), (8, 15, 22), (10, 11, 12)]
```